# Inserta datos de un array en Tabla Mysql en 2 campos diferentes

Tags: php

En esta oportunidad les traigo un problema que me esta rompiendo la cabeza y es no se como llamarlo pero es como "dividir este array e insertarlo en mi tabla horario la cual consta de 2 campos 'horaini' y 'horafin'.
El array en cuestion

```
Array ( [0] => 12:00:00 [1] => 12:15:00 [2] => 12:30:00 [3] => 12:45:00 [4] => 13:00:00 [5] => 13:15:00 [6] => 13:30:00 [7] => 13:45:00 [8] => 14:00:00 [9] => 14:15:00 [10] => 14:30:00 [11] => 14:45:00 [12] => 15:00:00 [13] => 15:15:00 [14] => 15:30:00 [15] => 15:45:00 [16] => 16:00:00 )
```

he probado con un foreach pero solo inserta todos los horarios en una sola columna. Creería que habria que dividir el array pues no lo se.

en la tabla solo me pega esto:

```
hora ini            hora fin
 12:00:00
 12:15:00
 12:30:00
 12:45:00
 13:00:00
 13:15:00
 13:30:00 etc..
```

Trabajo con PHP 7 y Mysql (MariaDB)

para la inserción a mi BD uso esta función:

```
function insertarBD($tabla,$campos, $valores){

  // Define an insert query
  $param = explode(",",$campos);
  $parametros = implode(",:",$param);
  $parametros = ":".$parametros;
  $Conn = new Conexion;

  $insertSQL ="INSERT INTO " . $tabla . "(" . $campos . ") VALUES (" . $parametros .")";
  $sentencia = $Conn::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO " . $tabla . "(" . $campos . ") VALUES (" . $parametros .")");
  $arr_length = count($param);
  $parametros1 = explode(",",$parametros);
  $valores1 = explode("|",$valores);
  for($i=0;$i<$arr_length;$i++)
  {
      $sentencia->bindParam($parametros1[$i], $valores1[$i]);
  }
  $sentencia->execute();
  $conn = null;        // Disconnect
}
```

la variable que contiene el array descripto arriba se llama $horarios
y la de los campos es $campo1= 'horaini' y $campo2= 'horafin'
y la inserto de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach ($horarios as $key => $value) {

        $todoPegado= insertarBD($tableName, $campo1, $campo2, $value);
        //var_dump($todoPegado);
  }
```

Pero el resultado final no es el que busco. Lo que busco sería asi:

```
horaini       horafin
12:00:00      12:15:00
12:15:00      12:30:00
12:30:00      12:45:00
12:45:00      13:00:00
etc..
```

Daniel segun tu respuesta esto es lo que hago:

$conexion = new Conexion;

```
$input = ['12:00:00', '12:15:00', '12:30:00', '12:45:00', '13:00:00', '13:15:00', '13:30:00', '13:45:00', '14:00:00', '14:15:00', '14:30:00', '14:45:00', '15:00:00', '15:15:00', '15:30:00', '15:45:00', '16:00:00'];
$output = [];
foreach ($input as $index => $time) {
    $output[] = '(' . $time . ', ' . date('H:i:s', strtotime(isset($input[ ++$index ]) ? $input[ $index ] : $input[ 0 ]) - 1) . ')';
   // $sql = $conexion::conectar()->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $tablaNombre . '(hora_ini, hora_fin) VALUES ' . implode(', ', $output));
    $sql =$conexion::conectar()->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $tablaNombre . ' (hora_ini, hora_fin) VALUES ' . PHP_EOL . implode(', ' . PHP_EOL, $output));
}
```

y también he probado meterle la variable que contiene el array asi:

```
$conexion = new Conexion;


$input = $horarios;
$output = [];
foreach ($input as $index => $time) {
    $output[] = '(' . $time . ', ' . date('H:i:s', strtotime(isset($input[ ++$index ]) ? $input[ $index ] : $input[ 0 ]) - 1) . ')';
   // $sql = $conexion::conectar()->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $tablaNombre . '(hora_ini, hora_fin) VALUES ' . implode(', ', $output));
    $sql =$conexion::conectar()->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $tablaNombre . ' (hora_ini, hora_fin) VALUES ' . PHP_EOL . implode(', ' . PHP_EOL, $output));
}
```

y no inserta amigo.

He intentado en vez de los campos poner sus respectivas variables y tambien he corregido los campos anteriormente ya que eran horaini horafin pero tampoco inserta. Hasta ahora todo lo tengo asi:

```
$conexion = new Conexion;
$tablaNombre = 'diahora';
$campo1 = 'horaini' ;
$campo2 = 'horafin';

$input = $horarios;
$output = [];
foreach ($input as $index => $time) {
    $output[] = '(' . $time . ', ' . date('H:i:s', strtotime(isset($input[ ++$index ]) ? $input[ $index ] : $input[ 0 ]) - 1) . ')';
   // $sql = $conexion::conectar()->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $tablaNombre . '(hora_ini, hora_fin) VALUES ' . implode(', ', $output));
    $sql =$conexion::conectar()->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $tablaNombre . ' ($campo1, $campo2) VALUES ' . PHP_EOL . implode(', ' . PHP_EOL, $output));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solución es simple, debes recorrer el arreglo y concatenar el horario actual con el (siguiente menos un segundo) por cada iteración, así:

```
$input = [ '12:00:00', '12:15:00', '12:30:00', '12:45:00', '13:00:00', '13:15:00', '13:30:00', '13:45:00', '14:00:00', '14:15:00', '14:30:00', '14:45:00', '15:00:00', '15:15:00', '15:30:00', '15:45:00', '16:00:00' ];
$output = [];
foreach ($input as $index => $time) {
    $output[] = '(\'' . $time . '\', \'' . date('H:i:s', strtotime(isset($input[ ++$index ]) ? $input[ $index ] : $input[ 0 ]) - 1) . '\')';
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' (hora_ini, hora_fin) VALUES ' . PHP_EOL . implode(', ' . PHP_EOL, $output);
```

En este caso puse que después del horario 16:00:00 el siguiente sea el primero, o sea 12:00:00

La consulta almacenada en la variable `$sql` es la única que se ha de ejecutar, pues contiene todos los datos. Otro detalle es que la variable `$table` debe contener el nombre de la tabla.

[image: El resultado...]

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta Daniel. Lo he probado pero me da un error y es este:Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in line 71 la cual es $output[] = '(' . $time . ', ' . date('H:i:s', strtotime(isset($input[ ++$index ]) ? $input[ $index ] - 1 : $input[ 0 ])) . ')';

Comment: Hola de nuevo Daniel Gracias. Ésta vez no da errores pero no se por qué no inserta nada He hecho la instancia de la conexion y para la inserción pero y he metido la sentencia dentro del foreach y no inserta nada.

Comment: La sentencia sql que coloqué al final, es la única consulta que debes ejecutar, prueba y dime.

Comment: @JuanPerez Prueba ahora.

Comment: Daniel Pérez Un Genio!! Funcionó!! Muchas Gracias Señor!! Solo una cosa mas Daniel como saco a lo ultimo el 16:00:00, 12:00:00 ? no los necesitos a esos 2 ultimo. Gracias!

Comment: @JuanPerez Sería cambiando lo que está en el foreach, sacando el ternario como un IF y negando la condición. En caso de cumplirse, salir del ciclo, así:
`foreach ($input as $index => $time) {
    if (!isset($input[ ++$index ])) break;
    $output[] = '(\'' . $time . '\', \'' . date('H:i:s', strtotime($input[ $index ]) - 1) . '\')';
}`

Comment: Un Genio muchas Gracias Daniel !